# Error: Datetime is displayed as value(42150.91666666) after using & to concatenate values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a macro which supposed to compile different columns of data into an email subject, the format of the data in terms of columns and samples are provided below:
[image]

However, the cells in column AD and AI which displays data and time must contain an apostrophe in the beginning, otherwise the cell would only display time, like shown below:
[image]

What's worse, without apostrophe, vba will prompt me the error message of

> type mismatch

To solve this I changed the concatenation character from `+` to `&` at this line:

```
.Subject = (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AD").Value) & (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AE").Value) & (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AF").Value) & (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AG").Value) & (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AH").Value) & (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AI").Value)
```

I have indeed solved the error message, but now the subject displays the date and time as value such as 42150.91666666. So now the problem I encountered is how to display the date and time properly, without adding the leading apostrophe characters.